# Tricky Update Problem

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the following table structure as follows: (please ignore the blackbox. was formatting the question in Excel)

[alt text http://img525.imageshack.us/img525/5788/beforeznj.jpg](http://img525.imageshack.us/img525/5788/beforeznj.jpg)

What I need to do is to transform the SessionGUID data into the following using TSQL:
[alt text http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/4553/afterjer.jpg](http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/4553/afterjer.jpg)

This is the user sessions table for my website and we screwed up the SessionGUID's in that it was generating a NEWID() on every page load. So now we need to group the sessions together by timing (assuming that a session breaks if a user does not trigger a page load 30 mins after the last pageload) using the first SessionGUID that was created.

Just to explain the short example further, User (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) visited my site twice on the 09/01/2009. One at 13:37 and another time at 14:46. User (A107EF1E-00A2-4515-A120-984086BC8368). Note that the actual table contains million of rows that need updating. :(

**UPDATE**
The landing page/starting URL for each session is not always 'homepage', it could be any page on the website. The plot thickens..

**UPDATE2** Test Data

```
CREATE TABLE Sessions (IPAddress VARCHAR(15), UserGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, DATE DATETIME, URL VARCHAR(200), SessionGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
INSERT INTO Sessions (
    IPAddress,
    UserGUID,
    DATE,
    URL,
    SessionGUID
)
VALUES ( '192.168.0.1', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '09/01/2009  13:37:34', 'homepage', '2B3A80B1-A247-4BB5-81BB-B54DED0C9C6A')
VALUES ( '192.168.0.1', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '09/01/2009  13:37:36', 'page1', '7FB10E12-5EB9-428C-BE3E-57818DEF8512')
VALUES ( '192.168.0.1', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '09/01/2009  13:37:41', 'page2', 'D12C3539-1239-447E-8BD8-DBA6B7087ADE')
VALUES ( '192.168.0.1', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '09/01/2009  14:56:00', 'homepage', '4FE36C46-640B-464F-8118-AFFE477347A1')
VALUES ( '192.168.0.1', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '09/01/2009  14:56:10', 'page2', 'FF9BF55B-3630-4D05-AB57-1B6ECAB96657')
VALUES ( '192.168.0.1', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '09/01/2009  14:56:18', 'page4', '863D3424-9788-481A-8440-09313ED4F8FE')
VALUES ( '192.168.0.1', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '09/01/2009  14:56:19', 'page3', '105D7FE5-C731-4EB6-B287-720127AAF0A3')
VALUES ( '192.168.0.1', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '09/01/2009  15:00:35', 'page5', '296479D0-3848-4189-94E2-41906BAE580D')
VALUES ( '192.168.0.1', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '09/01/2009  15:00:36', 'page7', 'E3FFEBC6-C11E-4DF4-81FA-B42F1BF7AFD3')
VALUES ( '212.1.1.0', 'A107EF1E-00A2-4515-A120-984086BC8368', '12/01/2009  18:30:22', 'homepage', '1F918AB3-34E1-4343-8462-FA56423B921D')
VALUES ( '212.1.1.0', 'A107EF1E-00A2-4515-A120-984086BC8368', '12/01/2009  18:34:26', 'page1', '801C3DC8-F0F3-4B9C-BD53-BCCBE784CFAE')
VALUES ( '212.1.1.0', 'A107EF1E-00A2-4515-A120-984086BC8368', '12/01/2009  18:38:17', 'page2', 'A9A5C2BD-31B9-4A9B-A8BC-88C460F17282')
VALUES ( '212.1.1.0', 'A107EF1E-00A2-4515-A120-984086BC8368', '15/01/2009  11:42:27', 'page3', 'B29CE754-C7A3-40E8-8CB0-216A3E852762')
VALUES ( '212.1.1.0', 'A107EF1E-00A2-4515-A120-984086BC8368', '15/01/2009  11:42:32', 'page4', 'E291C4B9-A422-4A76-A550-F65C208DD886')
VALUES ( '212.1.1.0', 'A107EF1E-00A2-4515-A120-984086BC8368', '15/01/2009  11:44:51', 'page6', '63D4A636-8336-44E7-8C97-9CD65D21359E')
VALUES ( '212.1.1.0', 'A107EF1E-00A2-4515-A120-984086BC8368', '15/01/2009  11:44:55', 'page2', '7BB814CD-C9B3-4CAF-A45C-4405DC0B07D2')
VALUES ( '212.1.1.0', 'A107EF1E-00A2-4515-A120-984086BC8368', '15/01/2009  11:48:35', 'page4', 'B6DCEC1E-C262-425D-8E46-8F4B47F2921A')
```

Thanks.

Unhappy DBA rookie.

Comment: "Assuming that one session lasts no more than 30 mins" Would it make more sense to say that a session breaks when a user has been inactive for some period of time (say 15 or 30 minutes). So if a user has a webpage served every minute for an hour, and then doesn't do anything for 45 minutes, that first hour would be in one session? Not knowing your website, I don't know if that makes sense.

Comment: You're right. That's what I meant to say. Updating now.

Comment: Sorry I don't have time for this today. You might look to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287148/t-sql-query-to-flag-repeat-records/1292182#1292182 for inspiration. Create possible sessions defined by start and end times of the sessions, start with the first session and then walk the possible session table with a recursive CTE.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with recursive CTE's but I see a problem in using it. Some of my users are very active, logging over 100 page views which goes past the boundaries of a CTE.

Comment: Stepping with recursive CTEs was for the original problem statement of a session being with time from beginning. Breaks are different. (See solution below.) Also, the recursion depth restriction can be adjusted or eliminated, see the query "hint" MAXRECURSION at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714(SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** I had a number of syntax errors, since I didn't test. (Note to self, don't submit answers without test code.) And to top it off, once I fixed the syntax, and ran against the test data, I found that my answer was wrong. The subquery testing for existence of a row within thirty minutes prior was completely bogus.

**Corrected version:**

```
; with EliminateTies (UserGuid, SessionGuid, "Date") as
    (select UserGuid
        , cast(min(cast(SessionGuid as varbinary)) as uniqueidentifier)
        , "Date"
    from Sessions
    group by UserGuid, "Date")
, SessionBoundaries (UserGuid, SessionGuid, StartDateTime, SessionNumber) as
    (select UserGuid, SessionGuid, "Date"
        , row_number() over 
            (partition by UserGuid 
            order by "Date") as SessionNumber
    from (select UserGuid, SessionGuid, "Date" from EliminateTies
        union all
        -- Add a set of records at the end of time, to bound the last
        -- of each users sessions
        select distinct UserGuid
            , null as SessionGuid
            , cast('9999-12-31' as datetime) as "Date"
        from Sessions) ET_Out
    where not exists (select *
        from EliminateTies ET_In
        where ET_Out.UserGuid = ET_In.UserGuid
        and ET_Out.SessionGuid <> ET_In.SessionGuid
        and (dateadd(minute, -30, ET_Out."Date") < ET_In."Date" 
            and ET_In."Date" <= ET_Out."Date")))
Update MT
    set SessionGuid = LowBound.SessionGuid
from SessionBoundaries LowBound
inner join SessionBoundaries HighBound
    on LowBound.UserGuid = HighBound.UserGuid
    and LowBound.SessionNumber = HighBound.SessionNumber - 1
inner join Sessions S
    on S.UserGuid = LowBound.UserGuid
    and LowBound.StartDateTime <= S."Date" 
    and S."Date" < HighBound.StartDateTime
```

**EDIT 2 Adding explanation:**

1. `; with EliminateTies ...` Define a relation called EliminateTies. This is to handle the possibility that the triples `(UserGuid, SessionGuid, "Date")` may contain duplicates for a given `(UserGuid, "Date")`. SQL Server datetime has a resolution of 1/300 of a second, so a duplicate is unlikely, but not impossible.

   1. EliminateTies will contain a row for every `(UserGuid, "Date")` pair `group by UserGuid, "Date"`.
   2. The `SessionGuid` is picked arbitrarily from the set of `SessionGuid`s available for that pair by the agregate function `min()`. As pointed out in a comment, `MIN(GUID)` is not allowed, so a cast to `VARBINARY` is made, `MIN()` is found, and then a cast back to a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`.
   3. Notes:

      1. I start with a semicolon because while SQL Server normally does not require a semicolon at the end of a statement, it does in the case of a statement that precedes a `with ...` Instead of trying to retrain myself to end all statements with semicolons, I have trained myself to start all `with ...` using a semicolon. The semicolon actually terminates any previous statement.
      2. I am quoting the "Date" identifier because date is a datatype in SQL Server 2008 and hence a reserved word there. OP is on 2005, so not strictly nescessary.
2. `, SessionBoundaries` Another relationship being defined. This relation has all the points where a new session starts based on the rule that for a given UserGuid sessions start when there is no entry in Sessions within the last 30 minutes.

   1. The inline view `from (select ... union all ...) ET_Out` Adds an extra row with a date at the "end of time" for each UserGuid. This is because we want to group the rows between a high and a low boundary, and we need an upper boundary for the last session of every user.
   2. `where not exists` filters out the rows that are not at the start of a session boundary.
   3. Within the select clause `row_number() ...` will number the rows, ordered by date, so that every `UserGuid` has `SessionNumber`s 1..N+1 where N is the number of sessions. We later use the SessionNumbers to find neighboring boundaries. (Could have been better called `SessionBoundaryNumber`.)
3. And finally the update. We add a `from` clause to allowing joining relations together. The update specifies the table alias of the table we wish to update from the from clause. (Note this is T-SQL and not an ANSI standard way to use multiple relations together in a view.)

   1. First we self join `SessionBoundary` by equality on `UserGuid` and by being neighbor boundaries based on `SessionNumber`. If user A had 2 sessions, there would be 3 `SessionNumber`s 1, 2 & 3. This join would result in (Low, High) pairs of (1, 2) & (2, 3). Now for every `UserGuid` we have the lower and upper boundary of every session. The upper boundary of the last session is "end of time."
   2. Next we join to the table we want to update, `Sessions` The join condition is that `UserGuid` is equal and that the date of the row in `Sessions` is within the range defined by [LowBound, HighBound). Remember the Boundaries are where sessions **start**. So the test is that LowBound <= Sessions."Date" < HighBound.

Comment: 1. Got rid of the MIN(SessionGUID) -- MIN/MAX not working on GUID
2. Added SessionGUID to GROUP BY

It's now saying "Invalid object name 'ElminateTies' "

Comment: Adding SessionGUID to the group by doesn't help. The point of the EliminateTies is to handle the (improbable, but possibly possible) case of two rows with the same datetime for the same UserGuid. And then yes, I had a number of typos. Thank you for the test data.

Comment: I'm having a bit of problem following your logic through. Do you think you could add some more comments throughout just so I can learn from it?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the additional data from your comments, I have to conclude that you don't have enough information in the table to *reliably* make this update.  You might be able to do some more analysis and find an acceptable timespan value you can group on and use for a one-time fix using something like Charles Bretana's method, but you'll have do that analysis yourself and you won't be able to count on that number or any number to continue to work long-term.

Comment: ok tricky thing here is the landing page isn't always 'homepage'

Comment: In that case, you really want a reliable way to signify the home page.  Otherwise you have to rely on grouping by the timestamps, and that _won't_ work.  You could pick something nice like 30minutes, but eventually you'll have a few sessions that run for longer.  If you stretch the time out to accommodate that you'll eventually have two users sessions close enough together that they overlap in your groups.

Comment: Hmm... even that may not be enough.  Who says users don't hit the home page more than once in a session?  But I do have an idea.  Give me some time and I'll see if I can come up with something.

Comment: You are correct Joel. But it seems I do not have a choice with the time limitations. Thanks for your time man.

Comment: Nevermind: the other method I was exploring required the first page in a session to always be the home page.  That may not be true.  Given that, I must conclude that you don't have enough information stored in your table to _reliably_ make this update.  You _might_ be able to fudge it with the dates, but over time it would eventually break.

Answer (score 0):

Does this look right?

```
UPDATE T Set SessionGuid = 
    (Select Min(UserGuid) FROM [mytable] 
     Where IPAddress=T.IPAddress 
       And Date = (Select Min(Date) From MyTable
                   Where IPAddress = T.IPAddress
                       And DateDiff(minute, Date, T.Date) 
                              Between 0 and 30)) 
FROM [mytable] T
```

Comment: Its returning more than 1 value with your sub query and not liking it.

Comment: @Nai, this would only happen if there are multiple rows with same IPAddress and exact same datetime.  But it is what it is as they say, so I edited sql to handle that.  Try Again?

Comment: It's not combining the sessions correctly on a bigger dataset. Thanks for your effort.